# gitlab-ci.yml looks for .gitconfig in different path than global user folder

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have my gitlab-ci.yml as follows, with reference to global config:

```
before script:
    - git config --global user.email 'myname@test.com'
    - git config --global user.name 'myname'
dev:
    git code goes here.
```

Please note due to NDA agreement, I am unable to share the actual yml code

My gitlab-runner is running on a Linux EC2 instance:

```
git version: 2.34.1
gitlab-runner version: 14.9.1
```

When I run the pipeline from my gitlab browser console, it fails with the following error:

```
error: could not lock config file /home/gitlab-runner/.gitconfig: no such file or directory
```

When I try to create the directory manually from the command prompt in my EC2 instance, am getting permission denied?

```
sudo mkdir gitlab-runner
mkdir: cannot create directory 'gitlab-runner': permission denied
```

Any help please how to resolve this issue.  I am curious why the pipeline is looking for /home/gitlab-runner/.gitconfig instead of /home/.gitconfig.

[image]

gitlab-runner user is already created, as follows:

```
sudo useradd --comment 'GitLab Runner' --create-home gitlab-runner --shell /bin/bash
```

The above command creates an user, but directory is not created.

Thanks